# How do you query different databases located on the same host with one pool connection and dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, connection-pooling

Thus far, I have been creating a separate pool for each MySQL database on the server and using dplyr to query them like this:

```
p1 <- pool::dbPool(
    drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
    host = myhost,
    port = myport,
    username = myusername,
    password = mypassword,
    dbname = mydbname1)
t1 <- dplyr::tbl(p1, "mytable1") %>%
    dplyr::collect(n = Inf)
p2 <- pool::dbPool(
    drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
    host = myhost,
    port = myport,
    username = myusername,
    password = mypassword,
    dbname = mydbname2)
t2 <- dplyr::tbl(p2, "mytable2") %>%
    dplyr::collect(n = Inf)
```

There are many databases, so that method leads to a lot of connections.  I would prefer to use only one pool and simply change the database,  but I don't know how to accomplish that.  I imagine it looking something like this:

```
p <- pool::dbPool(
    drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
    host = myhost,
    port = myport,
    username = myusername,
    password = mypassword)
t1 <- dplyr::tbl(select_db(p, mydbname1), "mytable1") %>%
    dplyr::collect(n = Inf)
t2 <- dplyr::tbl(select_db(p, mydbname2), "mytable2") %>%
    dplyr::collect(n = Inf)
```

Though, it doesn't need to have that exact form.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

From the [DBI](https://github.com/r-dbi/dbi) page, a DBI Connection is tied to a specific database:

> DBIConnection: represents a connection to a specific database

The [`pool`](https://github.com/rstudio/pool) package, then, is an abstraction of the DBI Connection object to be optimized for packages like Shiny or Plumber where a pool of DBI Connections *to the same database* is required to serve multiple simultaneous users.

As a result, you treat a `pool` object *like* it is a Connection object.

This, to me, implies that what you are suggesting is not currently possible and is not in scope for `pool`.

In order to make this type of thing less tedious, it would be possible to create a helper function that makes it *easier* to create a connection to a database (when all parameters are the same):

```
helper <- function(dbname){
pool::dbPool(
drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
host = myhost,
port = myport,
username = myusername,
password = mypassword,
dbname = dbname)
}
pool1 <- helper(mydbname1);
pool2 <- helper(mydbname2);
```

However, my understanding of `pool` means that 2 different databases means that 2 different connections or `pool` objects are required.  Said another way: `pool` is not meant to pool connections across databases.  It is meant to `pool` connections to the same database (again, in support of applications like Shiny apps and Plumber APIs).  Hope that helps!